# (Undergraduate) Differential geometry book recommendation

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, smooth-manifolds, book-recommendation

I'm searching a good undergraduate differential geometry book.

I've studied multivariable calculus, linear algebra, general topology, single variable undergraduate analysis and complex analysis and abstract algebra and so on.

Now I am studying "Analysis on manifolds" written by J.Munkres and it is coming to an end. (I will read generalized Stokes' Theorem part within 2 weeks.)

Is there any good undergraduate differential geometry book (using differential forms)? I would like to study differential geometry not only for differential geometry but also to review the multivariable analysis.

Now, I am thinking about [Differential geometry of curves and surfaces by Tapp](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3319397982) or [Differential geometry of curves and surfaces by Kobayashi Shoshichi](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/981151738X) or [First steps in differential geometry](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/146147731X)

Or is it better to read graduate-level differential geometry references for me? (After searching on the Internet, it seems there is a pretty large gap between undergraduate differential geometry and graduate-level differential geometry for me.)

Comment: I want to add one thing in "retroperspective" which I wish I had known earlier: Do you want to just learn a bit of DG, do you want to take graduate courses in DG, do you want to apply a bit of DG or do you actually want to do research in DG. Depending on what it is, different books might suit your needs better.

Comment: I recommend starting with a book about curves and surfaces. Not because it’s easier but because it has stuff  that you will not see in a graduate textbook. Since it is easier, you should be able to go through it pretty quickly. I also recommend looking for a book that used moving frames and differential forms.

Comment: Since you want differential forms and moving frames, I enthusiastically recommend Jeanne Clelland’s [new book](https://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-178/).

Comment: I knew Kobayashi very well but did not know he had written an undergraduate text (apparently, in Japanese). I see it’s based on moving frames, but I do not know what exercises are in that book — his famous graduate text has absolutely none.

Comment: @F.Conrad I'm just a undergraduate student, so I have no idea like graudate school or doing research yet... But I guess that I will take graudate Riemannian Geometry course in one year.

Comment: @Deane Thank you for your advising. I will read undergraduate book about curves and surfaces first.

Comment: @TedShifrin Then I will take a look at Kobayashi's undergraduate book along with your recommendation! There is a translation in English and I also use a little Japanese.

Comment: You can also download my free text. The link is in my profile. There are some good exercises, but the moving frames discussion is just one small section.